# Different between `Object.create(ctor.prototype)` and `new ctor()`

Tags: javascript, prototype, object-create

In VS Code 's source code, I found a pice of code like this:

(typescript)

```
/**
 * Creates a new object of the provided class and will call the constructor with
 * any additional argument supplied.
 */
export function create(ctor: Function, ...args: any[]): any {
    let obj = Object.create(ctor.prototype);
    ctor.apply(obj, args);

    return obj;
}
```

I think it's same with `new ctor(...args)`.

Isn't it?

Comment: Not the same, eg if `ctor` has `return { bar: 'bar' };`

Comment: So is it same if all `ctor` do not return a value?

Comment: Hrm, it well could be, but I'm not 100% sure that it is.